# Garage electrical

Tags: electrical, wiring

We are rewiring in our garage. The wire coming to the garage is very old and only black and white. At the junction box we want to hook up 2 lights, a plug and a switch. How do we go about this? The first time we-wired it, kept blowing the breaker. Now this time the breaker stays on and everything comes on with the switch OFF as soon as u turn the switch on the breaker blows what are we doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing how every single wire is connected it is impossible to know what you did wrong. Harper's guess is best with regards to a switch loop.

Comment: Voting to close. Question isn't clear at all, and not enough information is provided.

Comment: Seems like it's time to call a pro (or at least an experienced amateur). Lots of things can go wrong and risk lives.

Answer (score 3):

You're connecting all blacks to each other and all whites to each other.  Switch loops do not work that way.

Browse electrical books in the library or at Home Depot and find one that feels accessible, and read up as much as you can.  You just need to up the skills a bit :)

Comment: Thanks we were trying to get it done tonite and Home Depot or library aren't open this late lol

Comment: Use the [intertubes](http://www.howtowirealightswitch.com/) @Kayleen: